# How to handle 'Default_args' error in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I am getting this error:

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/reg_controller_new.py] type object 'DAG' has no attribute 'default_args'
```

I didn't find anything sufficient on google which can help me to figure out this issue.

Comment: Post the full traceback.Search for `.default_args` by grep in your code

Comment: Issue is been resolved ,thanks for looking on my question.

Comment: @SanniGupta Please post how you solved it!

Comment: problem is in my code ,i found it and fixed it.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it was a bad copy/paste from another StackOverflow question. I copied the following operator

```
t3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id=t3_id,
    python_callable=pull_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG
)
```

And didn't notice that it sad `DAG` (the class) instead of `dag` (the instantiated variable with `default_args` already set). After changing DAG to dag the error disappeared.

Comment: just for the record,  some people might send the dag_id string in the dag parameter instead of the dag instance and will get that error as well

Answer (score 0):

In my case, similarly to Alechan's answer, I had to provide the reference to the DAG to an operator, and I sent the decorator instead of the reference to the DAG object because I converted from

```
with airflow.DAG("my_dag",...) as dag:
    ...
```

to

```
@dag
def my_dag():
    ...
```

In the end, I had to revert back to the former.